# Redux / React: dispatch action while mapping over store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a parent component `CardList` that is mapping over the redux store and renders a `Card` component for each data-set found in the store.

My problem is that I can't dispatch an action to update the store.

I tried to dispatch `addLine()` in the parent (like shown below) and also I tried it in `Card` directly. Both did either nothing or the action fired and afterwards I got an error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

**CardList:**

```
(...)

function CardList() {
  const recipes = useSelector((recipes) => recipes);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <Link to='/recipe'>
      <ul>
        <section className='cardListWrapper'>
          {recipes.map((recipe) => (
            <Card
              key={recipe.id}
              recipe={recipe}
              onClick={() => dispatch(addLine())}
            />
          ))}
        </section>
      </ul>
    </Link>
  );
}

(...)
```

**Card:**

```
(...)

function Card({ recipe }) {
  const { title, text } = recipe;

  return (
    <div className='cardWrapper'>
      <h4 className='cardTitle'>{title}</h4>
      <p className='cardText'>{text}</p>
      <button className='cardButton'>READ MORE</button>
    </div>
  );
}

(...)
```

**Action & Reducer:**

```
// action:

export function addLine() {
  return {
    type: "ADDLINE",
  };
}

// reducer:

function reducer(recipes = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADDLINE":
      return console.log("this action fired");

    default:
      return recipes;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer returned invalid value. Try

```
function reducer(recipes = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADDLINE":
     // the problem was here
      console.log("this action fired");
       return recipes;

    default:
      return recipes;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see my error, I did not return the `recipes`. Thanks for pointing me to it.